# How to detect expanding ending, when pressing "*" on TreeView?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a control, derived from `TreeView`, which reflects some hierarchical data and creates nodes in lazy manner.
When a particular node is being expanded, I'm checking, is there a dummy node in its `Nodes` collection, and, if it is, I'm removing it, loading data from data source and creating real child nodes.

Data loading for node is surrounded with this construction:

```
Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
BeginUpdate();
try
{
  // node.Nodes.Add(...)
}
finally
{
  EndUpdate();
  Cursor = Cursors.Default;
}
```

This works fine, except one case: when user presses <kbd>*</kbd> (asterisk) on a node, which will load many nested nodes, and so on.
Because of code above I'm getting a blinking tree view, with a running scrollbar.

I thought, that expanding of a node with `ExpandAll` (this is what <kbd>*</kbd> does) ends, when all of child nodes are expanded, but this is false.

I'm wondering, is there a way to detect expanding ending in case of pressing <kbd>*</kbd> on `TreeView`?

Answer (score 0):

Can you not detect that the * key is pressed on a top most node and write a recursive function that loop through all child nodes and in turn if these child nodes have more child nodes, call the same function again, and so on until all nodes below the top most node have been expanded. This will will expand all nodes being expanded when the key * is pressed (and detected) and it will still handle your lazy loading.

Comment: Looks like inventing the wheel (two wheels). I want to prevent that.

Answer (score 0):

In your BeforeExpand event, you can look at the current level of the selectedNode, if it's zero, it is the top node. In the event, you will create your new child nodes and look if they contains other nodes, if so, add a dummy node inside. Your code will probably be almost the same as the one you currently have, but for the level 0 instead of level 1.

Comment: I'm not asking about "how to make lazy loading", sorry.